# Bad XML block: header size 28024 or total size 1702240364 is larger than data size 253 ERROR: Resource AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt

Tags: xml, flutter, android-activity, build.gradle, android-manifest

I am new to flutter and android development.
I am trying to add payment gateway in my app and made some changes in **build.gradle** and **MainActivity.java**
When i debugged my code i am getting the following error which i am totally unaware of.
Here is the error:

```
W/ResourceType( 9504): Bad XML block: header size 28024 or total size 1702240364 is larger than data size 253

ERROR: Resource AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt

Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed
  Command: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt dump xmltree C:\Users\admin\donationcard\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.

Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.donationcard">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="donationcard"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help me with some solution here.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? I'm running into the exact same problem with cordova because I upgraded from cordova-android 8.1.0 to 9.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` or manually delete the build folder.